# Prove $R$ follows from premises $(\lnot R\rightarrow\lnot Q),\;(P\lor Q,),\; (\lnot(P \lor T))$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, propositional-calculus

I'm preparing for an exam and we weren't given an answer sheet. I'd like to know if my reasoning for the given conclusion is correct?

Premises: $(\lnot R) \rightarrow (\lnot Q),\;\; (P \lor Q),\;\; \lnot(P \lor T)$

Conclusion: R

1. $(\lnot R) \rightarrow (\lnot Q):\;$ Given
2. $P \lor Q:\;$ Given
3. $\lnot(P \lor T):\;$ Given
4. $\lnot P \land \lnot T:\;$ DeMorgans Law #3
5. $\lnot P:\;$ Conjunctive Simplification #4
6. $Q:\;$ Disjunctive Syllogism #2 and #5
7. $R:\;$ Modus Tollens #1 and #6

I'm mostly unsure that #1 and #6 gives the conclusion $R$? I'm kind of guessing that I can put those together and get $R$ instead of $\lnot R,$ although it seems like there should be another step?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks good (your direction of reasoning is correct) but your proof may be seen as missing a couple of steps:

I suggest you  "play it safe" (and don't skip steps):

Write $\lnot \lnot Q$ (from $Q$ using double negation), to get $\lnot \lnot R$ by Modus Tollens, then use double negation again to get $R$.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply and that's exactly what I was wondering about, using double negation. So when I'm doing these if I need to just negate something are there any rules or anything? I mean can I just use it if I need to basically?

Comment: You can take any proposition $P$ and write $\lnot\lnot P$, and vice versa.  Yes, you can use it as you need it.  I'm suggesting you take care and not skip those steps. Of course, I completely understood your proof and such, and some professors might, after a while of doing proofs, be more permissive. But as I said, at this stage in the game, I'd play it safe.

Comment: no that's what I mean. Although it seems obvious our teacher really never formally told us that so just a dumb question I had to ask haha, thanks again